# Question on radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Can anyone help me with the following problem:

[image]

I have a solid geometric picture of what is going on in my head, but I can't seem to turn that into a proof.

Comment: It might help if you showed us the picture you have in mind and told us what's giving you trouble.

Comment: The picture gives a good line on the proof here, especially if you recall that $R(z)$ is the $\sup$ of all radii on which $f$ is defined. While I am not a fan, a proof by contradiction might work nicely here. Also note that there is an implicit assumption that the radii are finite.

Answer (score 1):

First, we see that if $R(z_0) = \infty$ for some $z_0$, then $f$ is entire and hence $R(z) = \infty$ everywhere.

So, assume that $R(z_1) < \infty$ (and hence $R(z_2) < \infty$ by the first remark).

Suppose $R(z_1) > R(z_2)+|z_1-z_2|$. In particular, choose $\rho$ such that
$R(z_2) < \rho < R(z_1)-|z_1-z_2|$.
This means that $B(z_2, R(z_2)) \subset  B(z_2, \rho) \subset B(z_1, R(z_1))$,
and the containment is strict.

To see this, if $x \in B(z_2, R(z_2))$, then $x \in B(z_2, \rho) $ and if
$x \in B(z_2,\rho)$, we have
$|z_1-x| \le |z_1-z_2|+|z_2-x| < |z_1-z_2|+\rho < R(z_1)$.

Hence $f$ is analytic on $B(z_2, \rho)$, which contradicts $R(z_2) < \rho$.

Switching the roles of $z_1,z_2$ finishes the proof.